# How to merge just added files from other branches in git?

Tags: git, octopress

I'm wondering if I can do selective merging, just merge back added files (that is, files in some branch with filesize changing from 0 bytes to some number)?

The reason is that octopress's `generate` is too slow such that I made a branch w/ only 3 or 5 posts left to help me write my own plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You must clearly understand one fundamental thing:

When you merge, you merge **not files**, but **changesets** (changeset is *atomic object*)

With this knowledge you'll be able to answer on own question: "You can merge only added files from branch to branch, if you can find changeset(s) with pure file additions in source branch"